LDS is causing an infinite loop while LES is working perfectly
This is my only code code.asm. I am executing this function from a .c file. But with this simple code, using lds instead of les causes an infinite loop...
_COD SEGMENT BYTE PUBLIC 'CODE'
    ASSUME CS:_COD
PUBLIC _cadena

_func PROC FAR
    push bp
    mov  bp, sp
    les  bx, [bp+10] ; using LES it works perfectly, but
                     ; using LDS it causes an infinite loop
    pop  bp
    ret
_func ENDP

_COD ENDS 

END


Presumably the C code expects a certain ds value.

What value are you loading into ds? What effect do you expect that to have on the behavior of the code after this function returns?

In addition to ds, typically bx is also expected to be unchanged when a function returns.

push ds and pop ds is solving the problem, why?

The C code probably doesnt expect ds to be modified.  What code is involved in the inf loop?

The C calling convention (CDECL) in x86 16-bit code defines volatile registers (ones that can be clobbered by a function) and non-volatile registers (ones that need to be preserved). The non-volatile registers need to have the same value they had upon entering the function when exiting.
The volatile registers that need no preservation are: AX, BX, CX, DX, ES, and ST(0)-ST(7). The non-volatile registers that need to be preserved are: SI, DI, BP, and DS.
You don't show your C code, but likely clobbering DS in func caused a bug in the caller upon returning. When you used LES to use the ES register instead there was no problem because there is no expectation that func has to preserve the original value in ES. When you used LDS and did push DS at the start and pop DS at the end DS was properly preserved and the code worked.
